# ¿Cómo se le puede poner un nombre a un input que me está capturando un id con el método get?

Tags: php, html

En el value donde se supone que se debe poner el nombre del input no puedo poner algo más aparte del id, ya que me genera error a la hora de su funcionalidad.

```
<input name="pedido-atendido" class="boton-pedido" type="submit" value="<?php echo $idPedido ?>"></input>
```

En el `value="<?php 'Pedido'.$id_pedido.' atendido' ?>"` necesito poner esto <- pero si lo hago así ya me dañará la funcionalidad del id ya que me pasa por la url todos los caracteres que hay dentro del value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que la forma de hacerlo seria teniendo un input oculto con el id real y otro para mostrar con los datos que quieres. 
Por ejemplo:

```
<input name="pedido-atendido" class="boton-pedido" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_pedido; ?>"></input>
<input class="boton-pedido" type="submit" value="<?php echo 'Pedido '.$id_pedido.' atendido'; ?>"></input>
```

Básicamente un input es para mostrar y el otro es para enviar los datos, por eso uno solo tiene el id del producto.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió demasiado.

Comment: Te recomendaría dejar el input que ve el usuario como disabled ya que el usuario podría pasar a eliminarlo y luego confundirse. Algo así <input type”te...... disabled>